# FTP upload Google Cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've created a project on Google Cloud to host my Wordpress website. Also i've installed the LAMP stack with the help of the click to deploy functionality in the cloud console.

Now I would like to upload my Wordpress code with the use of FileZilla ftp. Is this possible and where can I find the right Host, User name, Password and port in Google cloud?

I am new to Google cloud hosting and hope anyone can help me.

Best Regards,
Tim Vermeulen

Answer (score 2):

You don't deploy to the App Engine by uploading your files via FTP. You deploy using the SDK. You would do something like:

`$ appcfg.py update APPLICATION_DIRECTORY`

See [Quick Start WordPress for Google App Engine by GoogleCloudPlatform](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OSX then you can use Google Cloud Fuse. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse